Terraform how to use a resource from subscription A in subscription B
I have created an azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault in subscription A and when I create storage accounts in subscription B, I would like to enable the backup vault's principal id to be the storage account backup contributor. I have created in subscription B a second provider block, an alias provider block like this:
provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "backup_sub_provider"
  subscription_id = "xxx-xxxx-"
  features {
    
  }
}

and in the module that creates the storage account I have added this:
data "azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault" "this_vault" {
  provider            = azurerm.backup_sub_provider
  name                = "bvault-reb3az-vault"
  resource_group_name = "rg-reb3az-vault"
  }
  

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage_accounts["accntbackup"]
  role_definition_name = "Storage Account Backup Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.this_vault.identity[0].principal_id
}

This doesn't work and I don't even understand the error message from Terraform:
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with
module.client_instance.module.storage.data.azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.this_vault
its original provider configuration at
module.client_instance.module.storage.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"].backup_sub_provider
is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist
in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
module.client_instance.module.storage.data.azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.this_vault,
after which you can remove the provider configuration again.

I wonder whether it has to do with the fact that the alias provider block is in another module. My module structure is:
root module (has the provider and the alias provider block for the deployment)
  |
  + -- module x
  + -- module y (creates the storage account and references the alias provider)


To resolve the error, explicitly pass the aliased provider to the module that creates the storage account. In the root module, define the providers map to include both the default and aliased providers. Make sure the storage module contains a provider block that references the aliased provider. This configuration allows Terraform to correctly set up and utilize the aliased provider within the module. @Wolfgang

Thank you, this solved my problem. I don't know how to mark it as accepted solution.

Will provide the detail solution in answer check that out. @wolfgang
